# How to get average of values in T-SQL from specific table and join it's result with other one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, average

So basically, I have two tables:

- STUDENT {IdStudent Int (PK), IndexNr Varchar(10), Year Int, Name Varchar(32), Surname Varchar(64)}
- MARK {IdMark Int (PK), IdStudent Int (FK), Value Int, Subject Varchar(32)}

and as a first part of this exercise I need to run over them and grab all students from specific year (let's 2) and write out their average mark separately for each one of them.

I wanted to do this through cursor but I'm having troubles with it.
Mainly because I can't properly select these average marks using inner join.

For example I would like to return IndexNr and AverageMark.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.  Your query would seem to answer at least one interpretation of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by joining the tables and then use `group by` each student:

```
select 
  s.idstudent, s.name, s.surname
  avg(m.Value) AverageMark
from student s inner join mark m
on m.idstudent = s.idstudent
where s.year = 2019
group by s.idstudent, s.name, s.surname
```

but shouldn't the table `mark` also contain a `year` column?

Answer (score 1):

I think `GROUP BY` is what you're looking for: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

```
SELECT 
    s.Name
    ,s.Year
    ,AVG(m.Value) as Mean        
FROM Student s
JOIN Mark m ON m.IdStudent = s.IdStudent
GROUP BY
    s.Name
    ,s.Year
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average over *all* students, then you want one row.  Don't use `group by`.

You also need a `where` for the `year` condition:

```
SELECT AVG(s.Value) as Mean
FROM student s
WHERE s.year = ?  -- whatever year you want
```

Comment: My apologies but I've expressed myself badly in the topic (I've already edited it). Unfortunately I want to get average marks of each student separatly.